# Cannot build cordova iOS platform -- error 65 allowProvisioningUpdates

Tags: xcode, cordova, cordova-ios

I am getting an error trying to build iOS platform in cordova.  I have reinstalled the platform but i get the same error. This works a few day ago

Can you please help me resolve this issue

> xcode Version 10.0 (10A255)
>
> my build call..
>
> cordova build ios --release --buildConfig=build.json --device
>   --buildFlag=-allowProvisioningUpdates --gradleArg=--no-daemon`
>
> Here is error
>
> Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -
>   exportArchive,-archivePath,myapp.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/Documents/Development/mymobile/dev/MobileV2/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/Documents/Development/mymobile/dev/MobileV2/platforms/ios/build/device,-allowProvisioningUpdates`
>
> I have a build.json file that I use for the build
>
> "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer", "developmentTeam": "myid",
>   "automaticProvisioning": true, "packageType": "app-store"
>
> More --info
>
> 2018-10-19 13:01:08.558 xcodebuild[12415:403301] [MT] IDEDistribution:
>   -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path
>   '/var/folders/01/dln33_r97tzb95y8c1scy6bc0000gp/T/RandstadJobs_2018-10-19_13-01-08.558.xcdistributionlogs'.
>   error: exportArchive: "RandstadJobs.app" requires a provisioning
>   profile with the Push Notifications feature.
>
> Here an error I see but now sure how to resolve it. I have push enable
>   in the profile
>
> Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""myapp.app" requires a
>   provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature."
>
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="myapp.app" requires a provisioning
>   profile with the Push Notifications feature.,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the
>   "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property
>   list.}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable push notification in your project in Xcode, then select a provisioning/developer profile. Best is to allow automatic signing and select your Apple identity. It should do the rest on its own.

If you use xcode10, you also need to change the build system from new to legacy

> File -> WorkSpace Settings -> Build System: Legacy Build System

Comment: Thanks,,, but I have push enable in my project  and have automatic signing  and it was working.. The only change I made was to upgrade tp Xcode 10 because of the latest patch for my phone by apple,,,